# Accept image header request

Tags: http, go, http-headers

I wrote a route function, that accept only image request. Look at the following code.

```
// Add image route paths
func addImage(path string, handler httpImageFunc, name ...string) {
    //log.Println("Add image")
    if len(name) > 0 {
        router.Handle(path, httpImageFunc(handler)).
            Methods("GET").
            Headers("Accept", "image/*").
            Name(name[0])
    } else {
        router.Handle(path, httpImageFunc(handler)).
            Methods("GET").
            Headers("Accept", "image/*")
    }

}
```

As you can see, the requests accept only with header ("Accept", "image/*").
But chrome browser send a request with header

> Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

and firefox with

> Accept:image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

In this case, when firefox and chrome make an image request, it does not go through the router.
What do I have to do, that the request would be get through? I am using gorilla mux as router.

Comment: Hint: [`(*mux.Router).MatcherFunc`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.MatcherFunc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MatcherFunc and inspect the header yourself so you can match on "image/".